# How do I specify a range in the do until loop in VBA?

Tags: vba, loops

I'm writing a code, so that

```
Do Until Range("A1:A10")=5 

""

Loop
```

I want a certain range to all have the same numbers, but VBA keeps on telling me there's a type mismatch. It seems that you can only work with one cell at a time or you would have to use the "And" function?  (Do Until Range("A1")=5 And Range("A2")=5 , etc.)  But is there a way to have the loop run until a certain range of cells satisfies the condition?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
Dim rngUpdate As Range

Set rngUpdate = Range("A1:A5")
Do Until WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngUpdate, 5) = rngUpdate.Cells.Count
    'Your code goes here
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "for next", in your case:

```
For i = 1 To 10
    If Cells(i, 1) = "5" Then
    Exit For ' when cell value is 5, it exits loop

    Else
    *do other code*
    End if

Next i
```